# Run thread in background in java

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, background, chess

I'm writing a chess program in java. So far things are coming along fine but I do have a problem with updating my UI.

Here's a snippet of code from class ChessBoard which extends JPanel. This is called when a user tries to make a move:

```
if ( isLegalMove( aMove ) ) { // If the move's legal
    makeMove( aMove ); // Make that move
    select = null; // Reset some info
    drag = null;
    toggleTurn(); // Change turns
    generateMoves( 0 ); // Get legal moves for CPU
    repaint(); // Redraw board
    thread.run(); // Run chess algorithm
}
```

The thread is calling "run" on my instance of ChessBoard. The algorithm that finds the move can take several seconds to decide on a move.

I would like for my UI to update to reflect the user's move and then run the algorithm. That's why I run the algorithm on a separate thread. But my UI is not being updated until the computer also makes a move.

So if the user clicks a space to send a piece there, the screen freezes and then all of a sudden the piece has moved but the computer has moved also and it is again the player's turn.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure then that the code that takes a long time to run is in the thread? Or is it in `generateMoves(0)`? Will take you just a couple of seconds to find out with a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

`thread.run()` is going to execute the code in the thread's run method on the current thread. You want `thread.start()`.

[Relevant JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)

The repaint method doesn't actually repaint immediately. It basically tells the JPanel that it ought to repaint itself soon. Then you go ahead on the same thread and calculate the AI's move, which will freeze the window because Swing isn't multi-threaded.

Comment: I think you might want to re-think that answer (from the context of the OP's snippet). From the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) "*It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution*"

Comment: @MadProgrammer Although what you said is valid but 1) the "halting" behavior which is the main problem of OP is precisely caused by the run() method, and 2) from the code snippet we have no clues whether OP is reusing the thread instance.  It is possible that OP is instantiating the thread outside the if-block

Comment: @MadProgrammer As Adrian says, the only guaranteed problem here, based on his code, is that he's calling the wrong method. The section of the JavaDoc I linked him to clearly states that you can't start the Thread more than once, so if he reads the answer he'll figure that part out too.

Comment: @Chris So, we're now tracking the OP down the path a new problem instead, nice :D

Answer (score 1):

First, threads are not re-entrant (I'll explain that in a moment).

`thread.run()` is not causing the thread to execute in a separate thread, it's just call the `run` method of the thread (within the current `Thread`s context.

What you need to do is set up a condition loop within your `Thread` that you can trigger in order to execute the logic you need.

```
public class ChessThread extends Thread { // I prefer Runnable, that's me
    protected static final Object NEXT_MOVE_LOCK = Object();

    public ChessThread() {
        setDaemon(true); // This will allow the JVM to exit without the need to terminate the thread...
    }

    public void doNextMove() {
        // Notify the "wait" that we want to continue calculating the next move
        synchronized (NEXT_MOVE_LOCK) {
            NEXT_MOVE_LOCK.notify();
        }
    }       

    public void run() { 
        while (true) {
            // Wait for the "next move" request
            synchronized (NEXT_MOVE_LOCK) {
                try {
                    NEXT_MOVE_LOCK.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
                }
            }
            // Calculate the next move...
        }
    }
}
```

Now, `Thread`s are non-reentrant, this means that once the run method has complete, that instance of the `Thread` can not be restarted.

Hence using `thread.start()` more then once will not work (can't remember if it throws an exception or not) (hence the reason I prefer `Runnable`)

So.  What you want to do, is start the `Thread` when your program loads and when you need to, call `thread.doNextMove()` to cause it calculate the what ever it is you need.

Now, also remember, `Swing` is not `Thread` safe.  That is, you should NEVER update the UI from any `Thread` other than the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (or EDT)

You might also want to have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Oh and [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)