# Java: How to continue execution after thread is started?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm starting a thread which loops indefinitely until a certain event occurs. The problem is, I want to start this thread, and then return to the normal execution of my program. However, after starting the thread, the code seems to get stuck.

Code:

```
public void init()
{
   Runnable thread = new Runnable()
   {
     public void run()
     {
        while(something)
        {
           //do something
        }
     }        
   };
   System.out.println("Starting thread..");
   new Thread(thread).run();
   System.out.println("Returning");
   return;
}
```

When I start this, I get the output "Starting thread" but I don't get "returning" until the conditions for the while loop in the `run()` stop being true.

Any ideas how I can make it work asynchronously?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run thread in background in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188659/run-thread-in-background-in-java)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `start` rather than `run` to start a `Thread`. The latter just invokes the `run` method synchronously

```
new Thread(thread).start();
```

Read: [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: In other words, without calling `start()` you really aren't forking another thread.  By calling `run()` you are executing the `Runnable` in the calling thread.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this in your code:-

```
new Thread(thread).start();
```

like:-

```
public void init()
{
   Runnable thread = new Runnable()
   {
     public void run()
     {
        while(something)
        {
           //do something
        }
     }        
   };
   System.out.println("Starting thread..");
   new Thread(thread).start();    //use start() instead of run()
   System.out.println("Returning");
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `new Thread(thread).start()` instead of `run()`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure about your approach? You say:

```
The thread should loop indefinitely until certain event occurs.
```

that's an enormous loss of computational resource, the program is principally bound to get slow & fail. You may want to put the thread in wait() mode and catch InterruptedException to wake it up upon occurrence of your event of interest. If this preliminary understanding of what you are trying to accomplish is true then Id' strongly suggest you to revise your approach. Computing resource is expensive, don't waste it in relentless looping.

Comment: It depends on what he is doing in the loop. It could be for example: `while (started) { item = queue.take(); doSomethingWith(item); }`, which would be totally fine.

Comment: @assylias If there is a legit computation it is totally fine, however the author specifically says that "The thread should loop indefinitely until certain event occurs"...